# Determine keyboard tab position in an overflow container "tabindex"

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

hoping someone can point me in the right direction with the following code. I have a container that will have an overflow and each of the individual items can be "tab" using the user keyboard. However when this occurs it just cycles through the items and I was wondering if you can find which item is currently "tab selected" in the event you want to know where the user is. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="content">
      <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" tabindex="0" class="item"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden
}

.content{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.item{
  
}
```

Comment: `document.activeElement` can potentially tell you what has focus.  But your question seems strange.  Putting a tabindex of zero on things will not make it loop endlessly on just those elements.  An index of 0 just adds the elements into the natural tab flow of the page, which includes all other tabbable things, like browser controls and such

Comment: I used tabindex of zero to make the li items tab-able otherwise it cannot be accessed using the keyboard tab.

Comment: Right, I said that.  It adds it to the normal flow.  It does not restrict the normal flow. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex  *"tabindex="0" means that the element should be focusable in sequential keyboard navigation, after any positive tabindex values and its order is defined by the document's source order."*